# UWP/C++/Windows Runtime Component - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-app-center

I have try to add App Center in my project. My project has structure :

1. Blank App(Universal Windows) c++(TestAppCenter)
2. Windows Runtime Component(Universial Window) C#(CheckCrashComponent)

[image]

I have add app center in project (CheckCrashComponent). [Get Started with UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/uwp)

[image]

I call init in my project (TestAppCenter) like below :
[image]

it show error :

```
WinRT information: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
```

'Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
    or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

I have search on goolge but not find solution . If you meet the problem like me , please show me what i wrong in this case .Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Can you post your code as text, not as an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace class method with `static` method like below.

```
public static void  InitAppCenter()
{
    AppCenter.Start("11e4a636-6fa0-43b3-b2ee-dfde1f83axxxx", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));  
}
```

**Call Steps**

```
 TestAppCenterCore::CoreRuntime::InitAppCenter;
```

Comment: Could  you show me the difference between TestAppCenterCore::CoreRuntime::InitAppCenter and TestAppCenterCore::CoreRuntime::InitAppCenter() ?

Comment: The error still  occur after i change to static method .

Comment: Hi @ledien, I found I make a mistake, I just get `InitAppCenter` method instance, But I have not call it. I could reproduce your issue with above, it seem like VS compile issue. I found the same issue in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6d0d04e8-1471-4343-a78e-65c6405080cc/winrt-component-works-in-c-but-not-in-c?forum=wpdevelop), I have reported this bug

Comment: could you  get `a` instance with `new Class1()` method?